# Change starting and ending the Flex LineChart of JSON data with Slider

Tags: apache-flex, json, slider, mxml

My JSON Data file ise data.txt

```
[ 
    {
        "sayim":"1",
        "x":"400",
        "y":"5",
        "z":"-6"

    },

    {
        "sayim":"2",
        "x":"4",
        "y":"-40",
        "z":"700"
    },

    {
        "sayim":"3",
        "x":"5",
        "y":"-5",
        "z":"500"
    },

    {
        "sayim":"4",
        "x":"1400",
        "y":"50",
        "z":"-6"
    },

    {
        "sayim":"5",
        "x":"4",
        "y":"5",
        "z":"6"
    }
]
```

and my aim ise to create a Slider which can change starting and ending of the graphic, it is like what is showing in figure 6 in this [website](http://www.infoq.com/articles/flex-xml-json)

and here the MXML codes;

```
 .
                            ..
                            ...
                            jsonDataArray = JSON.decode(urlLoader.data);    
            proceed();
            }
         private function proceed():void
            {

                dgg.dataProvider = jsonDataArray;
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
<mx:HSlider  minimum="1" maximum="30" id="daySlider" snapInterval="1" thumbCount="2" values="[1,30]" /> 
    <mx:LineChart id="dgg" width="1000" height="500" horizontalCenter="0" > 
        <mx:series> 
    <mx:LineSeries xField="sayim" yField="x" displayName="X Bileşeni" /> 
    <mx:LineSeries xField="sayim" yField="y" displayName="Y Bileşeni" /> 
    <mx:LineSeries xField="sayim" yField="z" displayName="Z Bileşeni" /> 
        </mx:series> 
    </mx:LineChart> 
    <mx:Legend dataProvider="{dgg}" />
```

The problem is "dataProvider" definition in LineChart, I wrote this code but it is still not working,

```
dataProvider="{dgg(sayim>=daySlider.values[0] && sayim<=daySlider.values[1])}"
```

what is the right code to control the LineChart with the Slider.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing your metaphors a bit here.

In that article, he is using EcmaScript For Xml (E4X) to bind an XML query to the `dataProvider`. The "dots" in that line are very important because it assumes a loose XML tree.  It is also using a query syntax on `day` that can only be done with XML objects.  Thus, the following binding only works if the `stockData` is of the data type XML.

```
dataProvider="{stockData..day.(num >= daySlider.value )}"
```

In your case, however, your data is JSON, so your objects are not in the form that the query above will work.

Further, you are setting your `dataProvider` to call a function `dgg` but `dgg` is a `LineChart` and not a function.

In your case, I would recommend packing your data into an `ArrayCollection` and use `filterFunction` to define how to filter that data.  Then, bind to the `ArrayCollection` directly and modify the filter function proceeded by a `refresh()`.  You can see an example of doing this here: http://www.flex-blog.com/arraycollection-filter-example/

Good luck